# How to easily translate a array based language file?

Tags: php, translation

Many PHP projects are using array-like language files instead of Gettext:

```
$lang = array(
"lib_captcha_head" => "Confirmation Code",
"lib_captcha_insertword" => "Enter the words written below",
"lib_captcha_insertnumbers" => "Enter the spoken Numbers",
"lib_captcha_send" => "Send confirmation Code",
```

While translating it, I have to repeat select and type translated text in right side. The selection task often require mouse to do a quick selection (e.g. in UltraEdit or Sublime Text 2, I can double clicked the words and drag cursor to quickly select several words), this make terrible of my shoulder :-)

So is there exist any tools for me to simplify this task? For example, can I just use keyboard to navigate and select untranslated strings and input translations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with just the keyboard, but this depends on how powerful your editor is.

For example, if you're using Vim, simply stand between the quotes and type:

```
ci"
```

...which means: [C]hange what's [I]nside the `"` charaters. This would delete everything inside the quotes and you'll be able to type the new text.

It you don't want to type these 3 characters again and again and again, do:

```
:map <C-R> ci"
```

...which would bind the Control-R key to this command.